# Displaying data collected in previous step of workflow in current step

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

Here is the setup.  Creating workflow in Sharepoint Designer with two steps:

1) Collect feedback
2) Collect feedback2

Is there a way that you can display the feedback collected in step 1 on the edit page of step 2 or as a Field?  There is a Set Field action but i don't see any way to create a field....the only field available from the dropdown is Title which i would prefer not to use.....how can i add a field?

Answer (score 1):

My approach here would be to use 2 task content types and assign users a task as a collect data type action.  When the task is created, the list id value is output to a variable that can can be used to look up information.

After the task in step one is finished, you can create a new task with a new content type and lookup information from the previous task to use in the new task.